# Remove timestamp from each line in zsh shell

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to remove the current timestamp from my Terminal (macOS) using ZSH. I am using oh-my-zsh & I have the theme "pure" configured.

A timestamp appears on the very right of each line in brackets and I cannot figure out how to remove it.

**Example:**
[Timestamps are highlighted in red on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO2ZY.png)

**Update:** Terminal output example, I want to remove `[17:29:47]` etc from each line.

```
❯ cd ~                                                                         [17:29:47]

~
❯ ls                                                                           [17:29:49]
Applications Documents    Library      Music        Projects
Desktop      Downloads    Movies       Pictures     Public

~
❯ ls -l                                                                        [17:29:51]
total 0
drwx------@  4 gage  staff   128 Mar  4 22:27 Applications
drwx------@  4 gage  staff   128 Mar  7 15:39 Desktop
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by unsetting RPROMPT by adding `unset RPROMPT` to the end of my .zshrc file.

Comment: This didn't seem to make any difference in my case

Answer (score 13):

I was able to remove the whole right section in the theme which  showed `✔  123  10:46:22`

Open zshrc

`open ~/.zshrc`

Paste the following line at the end of the file. This hides the right section
`POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=()`

Thanks!

Comment: worked also fro me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

go to /Users/your_username/**.p10k.zsh** file  and search for **RIGHT_PROMT_ELEMENTS** and comment the time and status under it.

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
    # status                  # exit code of the last command ( commented)
    command_execution_time  # duration of the last command
    background_jobs         # presence of background jobs
    direnv                  # direnv status (https://direnv.net/)
    asdf                    # asdf version manager (https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)
    virtualenv              # python virtual environment (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
    anaconda 
  # time                    # current time
    # ip                    # ip address and ba
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands. They should get rid of the timestamps hopefully.

```
setopt noextendedhistory
setopt nosharehistory
```

You can put them in your .zshrc file too.

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference. I'm still stumped unfortunately.